# AJAX call PHP same page and reload option values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have an html form with a date input and a multiselect.
When loading page I load the options of the multiselect through a php function. 
What i want to do is to capture onChange event of the date input with a js script and launch the php script to reload the option values of the select using the new date.

This is the php code

```
<?php 

    //DEFINE 
    $dateMinimumInput = "";

    // Handle AJAX request for changing DateMinimumInput(start)
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && isset($_POST["dateMinimumChanged"]) ){
        echo "Inside function dateMinimumChanged: " .$_POST['dateMinimumChanged'];
        $dateMinimumInput = verify_input($_POST['dateMinimumChanged']);
    }
    $stationList = selectStations($dateMinimumInput);   ?>
```

This is the javascript

```js
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#dateMinimumInput").change(function(){
    //Selected value
    inputValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(inputValue);
    $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '',
     data: {ajax: 1, dateMinimumChanged: inputValue},
     success: function(data){
      console.log('works');
      console.log(data);
      $('body').append(response);
     },
     error: function(){
      alert('something went wrong');
     }
    });
    
    
   });
  });
    </script>
```

and this is the html form

```html
<form class="" role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group form-row"> 
    <label for="dateMinimumInput" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">Date Minimum:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
     <div class="form-group"> 
      <input type="date" class="form-control <?php if ( $dateMinimumInputErr !== "") { echo 'is-invalid'; }?>" id="dateMinimumInput" name="dateMinimumInput" placeholder="Enter date minimum" value="<?php echo $dateMinimumInput;?>"> 
      <div class="invalid-feedback"> <?php if ( $dateMinimumInputErr !== "") { echo 'Please, ' .$dateMinimumInputErr; } ?> </div>
     </div>    
    </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group form-row"> 
    <label for="stationInput" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">Station:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8"> 
     <select id="stationInput" name="stationInput[]" class="form-control" multiple>
      <?php
       foreach($stationList as $station){
        if($station['numberofmeasurements'] == 0){
         echo '<option disabled="true" value="'.$station['id'] .'">'.$station['location'] .' (' .$station['numberofmeasurements'] .') </option>';
        }else{
         echo '<option value="'.$station['id'] .'">'.$station['location'] .' (' .$station['numberofmeasurements'] .') </option>';
        }
       }
      ?>
     </select> 
    </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

The fragments of code are all from the same page.

The problem is that when I change the date, the javascript captures the event but the PHP script is not executed and the options are not reload.

Any help about what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: The url is empty for the ajax call. Have you tried putting the relative path to the php in there and see if it still misbehaves? (I know url defaults to same page, but I also _never_ rely on defaults)

Comment: In console, do you see a 'works' and `data` displayed? In network, do you see it hitting the php location with a request? You won't see anything in the `body` because you have `$('body').append(response);` where `response` is an undefined variable.

Comment: First of all, thank ypu for answering. I tried putting url: 'searchData.php', that is the name of the file from where i copied all fragments of code in my question, but it stil misbehaves. In  console I see 'works' and for data is displayed all the html page.  I removed $('body').append(response); but nothing changed.

Comment: We still need better details on 'misbehaves' ;) ... how so? what errors? anything returned? anything called? console spew? Mainly... I am asking "how do you know the PHP is not being executed"?

Comment: I think that the PHP is not being executed because the echo "Inside function dateMinimumChanged: " .$_POST['dateMinimumChanged']; inside the php script is not showed in the page

Comment: In the console page i don't have any error.

Comment: If you have no error in the console... do you have a "works" displayed, with a second line of data? I hate repeating myself here... but you won't see anything change in the body, because you are using `response`, which is an *undefined* variable.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not understanding because I'm doing these things for the first time...could you explain what shoul I do? Should I put in the success function the code to reload the page?